What's the hidden message in this text?
The text is as follows:

John has a girlfriend. Her name is Samantha. She is a newbie singer. She sung one of her songs in a charity. She is also an English teacher for foreigners. She broke her hand yesterday. She rushed to hospital to take an X-ray. After her hand healed she taught the vowels to her students (i,a,o,u,e). She is Mia Farrow's fan. She went to John's home after the class. John showed her an app he recently downloaded. One leg of the table is broken. The table falls on Samantha's foot breaking it as well!

This is an original puzzle.

 Hint 1: Everyone calls her Sam.


 Hint 2: John is a skilled Tekken player and his favorite character is a Chinese girl with pigtail hair style.


 Hint 3: Since John is American, all his belongings are American; including his phone.


 Hint 4: The answer consists of three words separated by commas.


The hidden message is pain.

@Sylvesterisoncodidact.com Is it a reference to a movie?

No haha, I was just joking about her breaking all those bones

Can you confirm whether or not the puzzle was basically unsolvable before you fixed "heald" to "healed" shortly after posting?

@LukasRotter The fixation of "heald" to "healed" was simply because I dislike typos. I even suggest editions every where I see posts with typos.

What about sung for sang?

@shoover Check the answer

@EtackSxchange My comment was more about the ungrammaticality of using the past participle sung instead of the preterite sang. "She sung" is ungrammatical; "she sang" is preferred.

@shoover Oh, my bad! But now I think it could be interpreted as an intentional mistake!

I have most of it I think!

 I feel like the first two words are Samsung (Samantha sung), Xiaomi (connected to the Samantha's vowel order + John's Tekken character Xiaoyu + MIa Farrow) , and that would mean the last one is probably Apple (connected to being an American company + he showed her an app) but I'm struggling to see how the table has to do with it!


For what it's worth, rot(gur ortvaavat bs gur frpbaq jbeq pbzrf sebz K-eln naq gur gnoyr'f yrt vf oebxra, fb gur T vf zvffvat. Gung'f ubj lbh trg gur -yr sbe gur guveq jbeq).

Excellent work. You did it right kwako. Table doesn't have anything to do with the puzzle. Leg is important.

@MOehm If I were you I would write ebg instead of rot :)
